# Using url values as variables in route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to declare multiple versions of an API inside different controllers in ASP.NET MVC. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "API/{version}/{action}/{id}", 
        new { 
             controller = "APIv{version}", 
             action = "Index", 
             id = UrlParameter.Optional 
        } 
    );
```

OR

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "API/{version}/{action}/{id}", 
        new { 
             controller = "APIv" + version, 
             action = "Index", 
             id = UrlParameter.Optional 
        } 
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've implemented it by moving different api versions into different areas

Version1:

```
 public class AreaRegistration : PortableAreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get { return "Api.v1"; }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "Api.v1_Default",
                    routeTemplate: "api/v1/{company}/{action}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Employees" }
            );
        }
    }
```

Version1.1:

```
  public class AreaRegistration : PortableAreaRegistration
        {
            public override string AreaName
            {
                get { return "Api.v1.1"; }
            }

            public override void RegisterArea(System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext context)
            {
                context.MapHttpRoute(
                        name: "Api.v1_1_Default",
                        routeTemplate: "api/v1.1/{company}/{action}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Employees" }
                );
            }
        }
```

Please note PortableAreaRegistration from MvcContrib is used.